# HTML5 Color picker embeded

Tags: html

So, in HTML5 there is this color picker:

```
<input type="color">
```

My problem is, this color opens a pop-up to select the color. Is there a way to embed the color selection in the page itself?

Comment: Why not using bootstrap datepicker?

Comment: 'Cause I'm not using bootstrap in my environment.

Comment: @RichardSocker Why would you use a datepicker to pick a color?

Comment: Too tired..... I meant color picker, maybe I used datepicker too much today :)

Comment: @RichardSocker No problem. Either way, I don't have bootstrap in my environment and it's not my environment so I can't add it. Plus, I've never used bootstrap before.

Comment: It's very easy you don't have to implement anything just download the utility include its css and js files and use them.

Comment: @RichardSocker I'll consider it as a possible work around, but again it's not my environment, so I'll have to pass it on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of [`input type="color"`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#color-state-(type%3Dcolor)) is left to the browser. There is no standard as to how it should be rendered. There may be browser-specific methods to style them, but as far as I know there aren't any cross-browser CSS properties one can use.

This control has [somewhat limited support (see caniuse.com for an updated list)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color).

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2021

If you are looking for something more extensive than the default HTML5 color picker, there is a library available called [shoelace](https://shoelace.style/components/color-picker) that renders inline color picker as mentionned by OP.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.0.0-beta.57/dist/themes/light.css">
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.0.0-beta.57/dist/shoelace.js/+esm"></script>


<h1>Input</h1>
<sl-color-picker size="small"></sl-color-picker>
<sl-color-picker size="medium"></sl-color-picker>
<sl-color-picker size="large"></sl-color-picker>

<hr>

<h1>Inline</h1>
<sl-color-picker inline></sl-color-picker>
```

Comment: The question is how to embed the native HTML5 `input type="color"` as a control rather than a popup, not how to use a third party control to do the same. There are [other questions which ask about generic color pickers](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+color+picker) on which this answer might find a place.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Should I remove this answer for quality sake or leave it?